# Upthrust vs Drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, projectile, drag, buoyancy

> *24: A ball is falling at terminal speed in still air. The forces acting on it are [upthrust](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=upthrust), viscous drag and weight. What is the order of increasing magnitude of these 3 forces?*

```
Answer :upthrust  < viscous drag  < weight
```

Could some one please explain why in still air upthrust of a ball is smaller than the viscous drag ?

Comment: I second John Rennie's answer. "Buoyant force" is what "upthrust" evokes for me in this context, but it still is not altogether clear. I see from the Google search it's often used to mean that in connexion with ships, although I haven't heard the word used thus before. I'm guessing it's probably more precisely defined somewhere in supporting text for your question set.

Answer (score 5):

Although it isn't absolutely clear from the question I would guess that the *up thrust* is the force due to [Archimedes' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle), so the up thrust is equal to the weight of air displaced by the object. Since the object is not accelerating, the net force on it must be zero so:

$$ mg = \text{drag} + \text{up thrust} $$

Obvious both the *drag* and *up thrust* must be less than or equal to $mg$, but their relative size will depend on the density of the ball. You would have to do the calculation to determine which was bigger. Unless your *ball* is something exotic, like a hot air balloon, a back of the envelope calculation should make it pretty obvious that the *up thrust* is a tiny force.

Answer (score -2):

Up thrust is approximately constant:
$$U=\rho\cdot g\cdot H$$

1. At $H$ height, air density low = up thrust
2. At $H-x$ (when object travel certain height), air density increase=up thrust

Comparing statements 1 and 2, up thrust is constant at $H$ height and $H-x$
**BUT**
drag or viscous force increases as velocity of an object increases,
so viscous drag is greater than up thrust.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability. I've added it in for you, but you may want to check the mark-up to ensure I've correctly interpreted your statements.

Comment: @user85417 Please do not reply to over-a-year-old questions which already have **correct** answers with **totally incorrect answers** invoking **irrelevant physical principles**. In this case it is sufficient to notice that a beach ball is a good counterexample where upthrust > viscous drag, proving both you and the quoted-answer wrong, and John Rennie above right. The air density has nothing to do with anything here.